# Trying to get codehighlighting-for-TinyMCE working with tinymce-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, tinymce, syntax-highlighting, tinymce-rails

I'm using the `tinymce-rails` in my Ruby on Rails application and I wanted to add syntax highlighting to TinyMCE then i found this plugin https://github.com/grena/codehighlighting-for-TinyMCE and added it to `app/assets/javascript/tinymce/codehighlighting`. also added to `tinymce.yml` like this:

```
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - codehighlighting
plugins:
  - codehighlighting
```

but when I load the view with the form with tinymce I get:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ed.onNodeChange.add')`

Did I something wrong ? or the plugin is not up to date?

Comment: hi could you show some code of view and please tell where you have placed the plugin and how you are loading it in assert pipelining(load path)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the plugin just like that since `tinymce-rails` only uses plugins included in the gem. You can find it here : https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins

So it's better that you should suggest the owner of this gem add your plugin, or better make a fork, add your plugin there and send a PR to them. It should work.